# Accessing rails sever on a virtual machine from host machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vmware

I've got Ubuntu (the newest version) running as a virtual machine on Windows 7 Pro, using VMware.
My question is, can I make the rails sever acessible to windows while the virtual machine is running?
So, for example, if I type on my Windows browser `http://localhost:3000` I would get the rails sever?

Also, can I make it acessible to computers from the outside, so if someone would type
`myipaddress:3000` he would be able to acess the sever as a client?

I hope this is clear.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of "ifs" here, but it should "just work".

In Linux, find the IP address of your virtual machine.

`$ /sbin/ifconfig`

You're looking for a section that is probably labelled "`eth0`" and in that "`inet addr`".

Using that address with port 3000 from your Windows host should work fine. If not, post the specific problem that you're seeing, including any logs you can find or info on any firewalls you have running on your Linux client.

Comment: It works perfectly thanks. Is it possible for someone to access the sever from outside? Say, if I'm at home and I want someone at the office to see my rails sever?